# How to calculate count of text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have put a condition for few cells in an excel as **Pass** and **Fail**.

Say there are 10 cells where one can select Pass/Fail. Now i need to calculate number of Pass and Number of Fail selected and the count needs to be displayed in another sheet.

Eg: In the 10 cells, User would have selected 7 Pass and 3 Fail. I need to display this count in another tab as 7 and 3.

Can someone help me with the formula to do this?

Comment: Use [`Countif`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-a8b3d1c2-309b-4e44-9047-e1746e90e55c?CorrelationId=41472f95-2f44-4f2b-9b89-f93b08a3a312&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) or [`Countifs`](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Pass")
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Fail")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for doing this is to use an array formula.

Something like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:A10="Pass",1,0))}
```

Or in R1C1 mode:

```
{=SUM(IF(R1C1:R10C1="Pass",1,0))}
```

It is very important to enter these formulas holding down the <kbd>CNTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd> keys together when hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. That's what makes an array formula work.

The advantage with this type of formula is you can make it quite a lot more complex than a simple `COUNTIF`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in single cell in different sheet you can use this formula using the concatenate method(&)

```
'=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A10,"Pass")&" Pass "& COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A10,"Fail")&" Fail"
```

Will result to:

```
7 Pass 3 Fail
```

Just change the name of the Sheet or the location of the data, sampled is located in A1 to A10 and on Sheet1

If you want it in different cells,

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A10,"Pass")
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A10,"Fail")
```

Will result to:

```
7
3
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use the COUNTIF function like so:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A10,"Pass") 
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A10,"Fail")
```

This assumes the sheet containing the data is called **Sheet1**